# Verbwahl: Modalität - "besitzen" oder "versprachlichen"?

Tags: vocabulary

Könntet Ihr mir bitte bei der Wortwahl helfen? 
Kann der Modus (z.B. der Indikativ) Modalität ***besitzen***?
Oder wird Modalität durch einen Modus eher ***versprachlicht***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich würde davon abraten, die Begriffe so schlicht zu verbinden.

**Modus** ist eine grammatische Kategorisierung von Verben. Dazu gehören die Kategorien *Indikativ* und *Konjunktiv*.

> Sie sagt, sie **hat/habe/hätte** von nichts gewußt.

**Modalität** ist das, was bestimmte Ausdrücke mit nicht wahrheitsfunktionaler Semantik zur Bedeutung eines Satzes beitragen. Klassisches Beispiel: Die Wahrheit von Sätzen wie

> Robert **muß** sein Zimmer aufräumen.
>   Es ist **erforderlich**, daß Robert sein Zimmer aufräumt.

ist unabhängig von der eines Satzes wie

> Robert räumt sein Zimmer auf.

Wie die Beispiele zeigen, können Modus und Modalität ganz unabhängig voneinander sein.

Comment: Danke schön! Die Sache ist die, dass der Ind. auch „Null-Modus“ genannt wird und ich wollte in meiner Arbeit schreiben, dass auch wenn er als Null-Modus bezeichnet wird, heißt es nicht, dass er keine Modalität besitzt. Aber ich liege da wahrscheinlich komplett falsch, uff